# Match fieldset width with button width

Tags: css

I have a `fieldset` and a `button` below it and i want these elements width to match. 
How could I do that ? 
I am new to programming and i don't really know much about CSS, so my field of knowledge is not yet very large.
Thank you.

```css
fieldset {
  position:relative;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0%;
}
button {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: i just did it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add width 100% to the button. Is it that what you looking for?

```css
fieldset {
  position:relative;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0%;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;  
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <button>btn</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It was not really that, but i figured it out, i just put the button in the fieldset, but thakn you anyway ^^

Comment: @LucasGillon ok. Yes the fieldset tag wrap your form elements and you can group it. You dont provide HTML and i thought that you already have it. In my example code i put the button into the fieldset. That helps you?